# How to determine the type of class and pass it to gson fromJson method brackets

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, gson

I am trying to create mechanism of parsing objects that are in the same sealed class and based on some sort of determination of type to be able to parse the string to this specific class.

So here is sample setup:

1) sealed class:

```
  sealed class Animal
data class Dog(
var name: String
): Animal()

data class Cat(
var color: String
): Animal()
```

2) the parsing method which parse json to this specific class

```
  fun parse(json: String, model: KClass<out Animal>) {
  //so how to pass the type of the "model" parameter to this brackets instead of question mark?
  val animal = gson.fromJson<?>(json, object : TypeToken<?>() {}.type) 
  //and then do something
```

}

So i think i wanna be able to use this like for example:

```
json = "" //some json
parse(json, Cat::class)
```

How to achive that?

The only way i can find now is something like this:

```
fun parse(json: String, model: KClass<out Animal>) {
  when (model) {
  Cat::class -> {
    val cat = gson.fromJson<Cat>(json, object : TypeToken<Cat>() {}.type)
    //and then do something
  }
  Dog::class -> {
    val dog = gson.fromJson<Dog>(json, object : TypeToken<Dog>() {}.type)
    //and then do something
  }
 }
}
```

But is there better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *reified* generic parameter ([Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters)).

The type parameter can then be used like a normal class:

```
inline fun <reified T> parse(json: String) {
    val animal = gson.fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)

    //do somehing with the result
    when(animal) {
        is Dog -> ...
        is Cat -> ...
    }        
}

//Call parse function
parse<Cat>(json)
```